# String comparison on pug

Tags: express, pug

I rendered the value on `status.js` like below

```
res.render('status', {
  status: JSON.stringify(status)
});
```

After that I tried to compare the value on my `status.pug` which is `Jade` template like this

`if status == 'success'` and also tried `-if(status == 'success')`

The result is always not equal

Comment: Can you print the 'status' value in your pug file using `h1 #{status}` and post the answer here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because it **can't** be equal to `'success'`. You pass the `status` variable to `JSON.stringify` which returns something you could save as a `.json` file. Is `success` valid JSON? No, so there's no way `JSON.stringify` would return that.

I assume that `status` is a string and (sometimes) has the value `'success'`. Calling `JSON.stringify("success")` returns `'"success"'` and `'"success"' !== 'success'`.

There's no reason to use `JSON.stringify` here. Just remove it.

Comment: I removed `JSON.stringify` as you mentioned, now the `status` is always inside `success` condition.

Comment: Then there's probably another problem elsewhere in your code. You could add `console.log(status);` above `res.render(...);` to check the value of `status`, maybe it's just always `'success'` .

Comment: I was wrong. After I removed `JSON.stringify`, it works. Thank you.